# Multiple Threads vs Multiple Processes

Tags: linux, multithreading

I am working on an application that needs to search an extremely large state space. In order to do this, I have been given access to a cluster node with 32 cores. My program will not require much memory (likely on the order of ten megabytes), nor will I need to do much IO (besides for outputting a solution when found to some text file). So my question becomes: is it better for me to write a program than launches multiple threads in order to perform the search in parallel, or is it just the same as launching instances of the same processes such that the search space has been partitioned evenly between them (specified with different command line arguments)?

In my case, the space can be searched independently, so I will not need any shared memory between threads/processes. I am only concerned about search efficiency. It it worth noting that this program will likely need to run on the order of weeks-months. Please excuse my ignorance, I am from a theoretical background.

Comment: CentOS 6 - Will be writing this in C/C++.

Comment: For a perfectly partitioned problem there will likely be no performance difference between using threads and processes. Use whatever you are more comfortable with. One advantage of processes though: If a single worker crashes, only that worker needs to be restarted, whereas in a multi-threaded program a crash in one thread can take down everything.

Comment: From a maintenance standpoint, multiple processes are also generally the way to go.  Since the data can be perfectly partitioned, it's easier to scale out to a more nodes for extra performance.

Comment: Multiple nodes/processes is exactly how the solr cloud is designed. Your search may not fall into a solr use case but the design seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of any other questions think on infrastructure and maintenance.
What would be more useful - to have one multi-threaded app, or multiple instances of the app.

If there is a chance, that you'll need to launch differently under different conditions, or on different physical machines/distributed, than multiple apps would be a solution, but this way you need to think of logs, deployment and other maintenance questions.

Generally, if you want to make it simple, than use multi-threaded single instantiated app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, go for multiple process. You will not have to deal with synchronization at all, and there will be no joining threads.